# Kernel of a symplectic form is one dimensional

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I was reading through "Lectures on Symplectic Geometry" by Ana Cannas da Silva.

In Chapter 10 where the book introduces contact structures, it says 
$ker \ (d\alpha_p)$ is one dimensional where $\alpha$ is the contact form. I do not see why this is true. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, we postulate that $d\alpha_p$ is non-degenerate on a hyperplane $H$ (which implies that $H$ is even dimensional). This implies that considered as a form on ambient tangent space $d\alpha_p$ can not have kernel of dimension higher than 1 -- otherwise that kernel will intersect the hyperplane non-trivially, leading to a contradiction. On the other hand, being an anti-symmetric form on an odd dimensional space $d\alpha_p$  must have a non-trivial kernel. So the kernel is one dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much @Max, you made it all clear.